# HTTP PATCH ADD/Remove field on resource

Tags: rest

HTTP PATCH is used for partial updates for the resource. And as per my understanding following updates are possible on resource which are relevant to PATCH (Could be more but I need to know exactly how these two are handled differently)

1. Updating a field like Mobile Number on Customer resource
2. Add a New Telephone Number field on existing Customer Resource like a Telephone Number[4] is introduced as a new field

I just want to know that whether PATCH should handle the second scenario or not? If yes then how should it be and how it be differ from the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PATCH requires a document format which is able to describe a set of changes to modify the target resource. The format itself is not standardized by HTTP and its up to you to choose the format you're going to use. This might be a simple diff file, or something designed specifically for serialized formats, like the [JSON-patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) format, for instance.

Considering that, PATCH can be used for any partial updates that can be performed by the patching algorithm you decided to use. If the media-type for the Customer resource allows a telephone number to be added as a new field, it's perfectly fine to use PATCH to add that, if the patching algorithm used can perform additions.

Comment: Hi  Pedro.. Thanks for answering. Probably JSON-patch is one of the good option which can be used here. Do you  know any other patching algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use but a method `PATCH` but I think that in your case (second scenario) using the method `POST` is more convenient:

```
POST /users/<userid>/phones
Content-type: text/plain
+33 3 12 34 56 78

201 Created
```

**Edited:**

Following your comment, the method `PATCH` is what you need. Here are some links that could help you to define the format of the payload for your request:

- [REST API - Bulk Create or Update in single request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596688/rest-api-bulk-create-or-update-in-single-request/28720881#28720881)
- http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/

Otherwise you can notice that OData directly provides the data in the payload. See this link http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/, section "Update an Entity".

Hope it helps you,
Thierry