# A RESTful way of updating all the resources

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-core

I want to make a common change to all the resources an API exposes. For instance, suppose an API exposing all the students of a class, and you want to set a common course for all of the students.

One way would be to query the API, and one-by-one or in batch update a property of resources. However, that would require first getting all the resources, then update their property, and then send and post request.

Instead, I am interested in a RESTful design where you can send a property and its value, which will be applied on **all** the resources exposed via an API (e.g., students in the previous example).

Any suggestion on how this can be achieved via a RESTful design?

## Update 1:

In other words, I would like to update **one** field of all the resources to a common value without having to fetch the resources first. So, I do not want to implement something as the following, because I have millions of resources that I do not want to fetch all their IDs first and then create a json object as the following:

```
PATCH /items
[ { id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' } ]
```

Comment: Just see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596688/rest-api-bulk-create-or-update-in-single-request). I suggest you to use PATCH method with list on it.

Comment: please see my update.

Comment: I still think my answer is correct.  You don't want to change a student, you want to change a class.

Comment: But that is not comprehensive; e.g., how could you use that method to set every students family name to an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

**Use PATCH.** Reference [RFC5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) and [RFC6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) for more details.

Sample:

```
PATCH /api/classes/123/students
[ { id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' } ]
```

You will have to choose how to handle error your response, either making it atomic or not.

- For atomic, a failed row will make your whole request `400`.
- For non-atomic, you'll have `200` from the server with error details in its body.

Both cases have pros and cons from API consumer perspective. Decision should be made in regard to your use case.

**Update 1:**

By not supplying a list to an endpoint without specific ID, you're doing that action with the whole collection.

Providing a JSON body like this should be setting all provided properties to value specified for every records in that collection:

```
PATCH /api/classes/123/students
{ courses: [ commonCourse1, commonCourse2 ] }
```

Comment: you still rely on `classes` but in my scenario there could be cases where I don't have any synonym to `class` (e.g., `name` as in my question, that necessarily there is no model for it).

Comment: @Hamed I use `classes` as example in regard to your question where you want to set a common course for all of the students in a class. You can actually use this approach with any collection.

As for the `name` you mentioned, I see you assign different name for each item, but I understand from your question that you want to update one field of all the resources to a common value?

I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Yes, I would like to update a field of all the resources to a common value.

Comment: @Hamed If that's the case, then the solution I provided is essentially that. Just specify the values you want and PATCH them into the collection. The example I provided will update every students inside class 123 to have their `courses` updated to a common value provided in request body. You can just remove `classes` from the url if you want to specify it for every students regardless of their class. I don't understand why did you mention `classes` at all in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If the students are already allocated to a class then I don't think there's a problem with changing them en-bloc with something like:

```
/api/class/123/updateCourse?newCourse=456

class ClassController
{
   public IResult UpdateCourse(int class, int newCourse)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still create an endpoint just like /items/update/all and pass your value:

```
POST /api/items/update/all 
{
  "value": 123
}
```

Next you just need properly handle it. For example, just write SQL query like:

```
UPDATE Items
SET value=POST["value"];
```